# C# regex. Nested tags. Matching spoilers and converting them to bbcode

Tags: c#, regex, tags, nested, bbcode

I have the following html code, which have nesting up to level 3:

```
<div class="sp-wrap">
    <div class="sp-body" title="FAQ">
        Some text
        <div class="sp-wrap">
            <div class="sp-body" title="title1"> // Level 2
            Text1...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sp-wrap">
            <div class="sp-body" title="title2"> // Level 2
            Text2...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sp-wrap">
            <div class="sp-body" title="title3"> // Level 2
            Text3...
            <div class="sp-wrap">
                <div class="sp-body" title="title4"> // Level 3
                Text4...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to replace div tags into bbcode and my regular expression work only for not nested spoilers:

```
Regex.Replace(outstring, 
              @"<div class=""sp-body"" title=""(.*?)"">(.*?)</div>", 
              "[spoiler=$1]$2[/spoiler]", 
              RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not test, but the idea should work:

```
string s1 = Regex.Replace(outstring, @"<div class=""sp-body"" title=""(.*?)"">", "[spoiler=$1]", RegexOptions.Singleline);
string s2 = Regex.Replace(s1, @"</div>", "[/spoiler]", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

**EDIT:**

```
string s1 = Regex.Replace(outstring, @"<div class=""sp-wrap"">\s*<div class=""sp-body"" title=""(.*?)"">", "[spoiler=$1]", RegexOptions.Singleline);
string s2 = Regex.Replace(s1, @"</div>\s*</div>", "[/spoiler]", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Should produce something like

```
[spoiler=FAQ]
    Some text
    [spoiler=title1] // Level 2
        Text1...
        [/spoiler]
    [spoiler=title2] // Level 2
        Text2...
        [/spoiler]
    [spoiler=title3] // Level 2
        Text3...
        [spoiler=title4] // Level 3
            Text4...
            [/spoiler]
    [/spoiler]
</div>
```

As you can see it's not perfectly indented (could be fixed, I guess) and detects one missing `</div>` in the example.

Comment: In my html code i have not only divs with class sp-body, so replacing </div> its a bad idea.

Comment: You mean, other then sp-wrap? These sp-wraps, when used as in the example, are easily avoided, but if you hava a whole bunch of different classes, this simple way would not work. Ever considered a HTML parser?

Comment: No. Spoiler consist only of 2 divs sp-body inside sp-wrap. How we can avoid divs with sp-wrap?

Comment: Thanks. This regular expression work only in case when we have nested spoilers, but if we haven't?

Comment: You mean after edit? Yes. If sp-wrap is optional, you could run them all (those before edit LATER than those after edit).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it will replace only the divs which are the first occurrence and the next closest /div occurrence

```
<div>                    // replaced
    <div>                // not replaced 
    </div>               // replaced
</div>                   // not replaced
```

One way to do it is to load it into XML and then modify only the nodes you're interested in using XPATH. In case of a HTML, you could also use an HTML parser and then use CSS selectors.

You can easily modify the opening divs (by matching against class), but there is no way for a regular expression to know which is the corresponding ending div.

Answer (score 0):

This task doesn't been fully completed with Regex methods. Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing Html

Comment: I use it for matching, but how we can replace html tags to bbcode, according my example?

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop for your regex:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"<div class=""sp-body"" title=""(.*?)"">(.*?)</div>");
while (rgx.IsMatch(outstring))
{
    outstring = rgx.Replace(outstring, "[spoiler=$1]$2[/spoiler]");
}
```